# creating a reusable control

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xib

(Using IOS 6, XCode 4.6, ARC, Storyboard)

I'm Trying to create a reusable `UIView` (like user control in C#), because I have two viewControllers having the same data one for input and other for display.

I read here that the way to do it is by creating a separate xib file for the ReusableUIView, as well as creating corresponding h + m files for it. Adding all the controls and linking the outlets to them.

In the storyboard I have `UIViewController`, in its `viewDidLoad` i wrote the following code:

```
NSArray *myNibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReusableUIView" owner:self options:nil];
ReusableUIView *myCustomView = [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Few questions:

1. nothing happens at this point so I'm guessing i have to connect somehow self (the UIViewController) with myCustomView
2. The ReusableUIView is one of many controls in the UIViewController how do i set it's place
3. In the xib file i can't find a way to set the size of the UIView, where and when we set the size of it

Answer (score 0):

1. It is better to custom view loading it its class itself - add some static method in your custom view class that will look like this:

   > '+' (ReusableUIView *) loadView {
   >
   > > ReusableUIView *loadedView = nil;
   > >
   > > NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ReusableUIView"
   > >     owner:self options:nil];
   > >
   > > if ([nibs count] > 0) {
   > >
   > > > loadedView = [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
   > > >
   > > > }
   > >
   > > return loadedView;
   >
   > }
2. As ReusableUIView inherits UIView you can easily config its sizes and positions using frame property and adding it as a subview on parent view.
3. I am not sure what is the problem, but you can change view sizes in xib easily.

Also, please note two things:

1. When you are loading view from nib then ***- (id) initWithCoder(NSCoder **)aDecoder** constructor method is calles. So if you need any additional setups - you have to implement then in this method.
2. When you are making custom view with xib and .h/.m files you have to mark you custom class in xib not on files owner but directly on your UIView.

Comment: 1. so the ViewController will call the loadView class method and initialize the subview with it?  2. in the Xib the width and height properties of ReusableUIView are disabled in the attribute inspector    3. How do I mark the custom class in xib not on files owner but directly on your UIView.

Comment: 1. Yes, in this case you will be able to call loadView method instead of direct calling of nub loading. -2. Try to change view property "Size" in property inspector to "Freeform" in your xib. 3. When you are in xib you can see 3 items: file's owner, first responder and your UIView directly. You have to select UIView, then activate third from left menu item in inspector and select your ReusableUIView in Custom Class field. Does it make sense?